# How to disable minified in vue-cli?

Tags: vue.js, vue-cli, vue-cli-3, vue-cli-4

I wanna the production code is not minified in `dist/` with `@vue/cli 4.1.2`

1、first try
set `vue.config.js`

```js
module.exports = {
  chainWebpack: config => {
  config.optimization.minimize(false)
  }
}
```

and then other parts is normal, but the inline script still be minified.

```js
var Appvue_type_template_id_7a951895_render = function () {var _vm=this;var _h=_vm.$createElement;var _c=_vm._self._c||_h;return _c('div',{attrs:{"id":"app"}},[_c('img',{attrs:{"alt":"Vue logo","src":__webpack_require__("cf05")}}),_c('HelloWorld',{attrs:{"msg":"Welcome to Your Vue.js App"}})],1)}
```

2、 second try

use dev mode `vue-cli-service build --mode development`

but the code format is `eval(...)`

Answer (score -1):

have a try to delete the plugin like:
config.optimization.minimizers.delete(name)
`vue inspect --plugins` to check plugin names
maybe `terser`?